# Formatting a number to ordinal number? (1st, 2nd, etc..)

Tags: cocoa, nsnumberformatter

is there a way to format a number in cocoa to its ordinal string 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc... Preferably localized aware?
Thank you,
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ADNOrdinalNumberFormatter](https://github.com/Abizern/ADNOrdinalNumberFormatter) does ordinal   formatting but is unfortunately not localization aware.

Answer (score 13):

As of iOS 9.0+, macOS 10.11+, tvOS 9.0+, and watchOS 2.0+, this is in Foundation:

### Swift

```swift
let ordinalFormatter = NumberFormatter()
ordinalFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal

print(ordinalFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 3))) // 3rd
```

### Objective C

```objc
NSNumberFormatter * ordinalFormatter = [NumberFormatter new];
ordinalFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle;

NSLog([ordinalFormatter stringFromNumber: @3]); // 3rd
```

Answer (score 0):

[TTTOrdinalNumberFormatter](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit/blob/0.6.0/TTTOrdinalNumberFormatter/TTTOrdinalNumberFormatter.h) from [FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit) does ordinal formatting in the following languages:

- Chinese
- Dutch
- English
- French
- German
- Italian
- Irish
- Japanese
- Portuguese
- Spanish